# Get coordinates from Point Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I use class with PointField to store coordinates in database.

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class MapPoint(models.Model):
    p = models.PointField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p
```

Coordinates I get from template using AJAX.

```
# views.py

def mapper(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.is_ajax():
            lat = float(request.GET.get('lat'))
            lng = float(request.GET.get('lng'))
            pnt = Point(lat, lng)
            MapPoint.objects.create(p=pnt)

    return render(request, 'map_in.html')
```

Then I want to show all points in other template

```
# views.py

def mapper_done(request):
    query = MapPoint.objects.all().values()
    out_list = list(query)
    return render(request, 'map_out.html', {'out_list': out_list})
```

It returns:

```
{'id': 1, 'p': <Point object at 0x7f42c712b670>}
```

How can I get coordinates from Point? I want something like this:

```
ID: 1, lat: 42.326565 lng: 52.325874
```

As I see, I need to iterate through querySet. But how?

And sorry for bad English:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> pnt = Point(5, 23)
>>> [coord for coord in pnt]
[5.0, 23.0]
>>> pnt.coords
(5.0, 23.0)
```

add your variable
pnt = Point(your point variable)

Answer (score 6):

point is a python object so it has some attributes that you can use for example
`p.coords` will get you a tuple of `(longitude, latitude)` so you can get:

```py
lat = p.coords[1]
lon = p.coords[0]
```

also in your code you are instantiating the point object wrong the `(longitude, latitude)` is the right format for it as well
always check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#geometry-objects)

Comment: I get coordinates from template in str type. And if I left it like that, it raise an error. And thank for your help, it worked!

Comment: yes you should cast it to float but i meant the order of creating a point object is that Point( longitude, latitude)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch `lat`, `lng` values from database using [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Func, FloatField


class GeometryPointFunc(Func):
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s::geometry)"

    def __init__(self, expression: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(expression, output_field=FloatField())


class Latitude(GeometryPointFunc):
    function = "ST_Y"


class Longitude(GeometryPointFunc):
    function = "ST_X"
```

Then use in queryset:

```
query = MapPoint.objects.annotate(lat=Latitude("p"), lng=Longitude("p")).values()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def mapper_done(request):                                                          
    query = MapPoint.objects.all()                                   
    out_list = [{'ID': i.id,                                                    
         'lat': i.p.x,                                                          
         'lon': i.p.y} for i in query]                                                                                                                                                                             
    return render(request, 'map_out.html', {'out_list': out_list})
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but this cod raise an error:`Exception Type: AttributeError at /map/done/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'ID'`. The same with 'p'

Answer (score 0):

I annotated a queryset with `lat` and `lon` separately, as floats. [Evgeni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325438/4744341) put me on the right track, but I ended up doing it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Func, FloatField

query = MapPoint.objects.annotate(
    lat=Func("p", function="ST_Y", output_field=FloatField()),
    lon=Func("p", function="ST_X", output_field=FloatField()),
).values()

for place in query:
    print(place)
# {'id': 1, 'lat': 52.018948, 'lon': 8.819528}
# {'id': 2, 'lat': 53.692242, 'lon': 9.373505}
# ...
```